# Localization don't work on a ModelForm in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-i18n

```
def Person(models.Model)
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       birth_date = models.DateField()
```

and I have this form

```
def PersonForm(forms.ModelForm)

   class Meta:
      model = Person
```

I have to localize the project to spanish (es), and add a customized format module (FORMAT_MODULE_PATH) to set DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y'. Everything works fine if I only show dates in the template, but when the form is diplayed with data from the database, the input control show the date as Y-m-d

How can I fix that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513502/django-how-to-format-a-datefields-date-representation