# Is there a way customize the default template output of a model field?

Tags: django

my model:

```
class StackOverflowQuestion(models.Model):
     published_date = models.DateTimeField(...)
```

template1.html:

```
{% load mytagsandfilters %}

{{ question.published_date|show_date_the_way_management_wants_it:"D d M Y" }}
```

template2.html  (...basically identical to template1.html)

```
{% load mytagsandfilters %}

{{ another_question.published_date|show_date_the_way_management_wants_it:"D d M Y" }}
```

**My goal:  I want to remove the use of the template filter because it's duplicated in two places.**

This would leave me something way cleaner:

template1.html

```
{% load mytagsandfilters %}

{{ question.published_date }}
```

template2.html

```
{% load mytagsandfilters %}   

{{ another_question.published_date }}
```

so...

Q.  Is there a way maybe to override a method in the StackOverflowQuestion model class to do this?  Or maybe a way to subclass models.DateTimeField to do it?  Or some other way?

Comment: note note:  I'm not looking for the DATE_FORMAT setting as I need to write some Python to implement a set of requirements etc.

Comment: oh also, i tried subclassing models.DateTimeField and overriding __ unicode __  ...but that doesn't appear to be the right spot/way

Comment: The only way I know of is to build a custom model field (fields specify a default widget). I wish I could override the default modelform engine widget per model field instance. Starring

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to customize [DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_FORMAT) in your settings.py, you can still act at the form level. As mentionned [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513502/django-how-to-format-a-datefields-date-representation),  the [DateInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateInput) widget should do the trick.