# Strange behaviour of date fields in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have internationalization on:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de_AT'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

When the admin views the form for a model:

- On the first request a DateTime field is shown in the correct format. But saving gives a format violation.
- After a reload, the DateTime field is shown in US format. Saving then works.

Any hints, where to look further?

Version infos: Django==1.7 django-grappelli==2.6.1 django-mptt==0.6.1 psycopg2==2.5.4 pytz==2014.7 wsgiref==0.1.2 xlrd==0.9.3

Comment: This will help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513502/django-how-to-format-a-datefields-date-representation

Answer (score 0):

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%d.%m.%Y', '%d.%m.%Y', '%d.%m.%y',  # '25.10.2006', '25.10.2006', '25.10.06'
    '%d-%m-%Y', '%d/%m/%Y', '%d/%m/%y',  # '25-10-2006', '25/10/2006', '25/10/06'
    '%d %b %Y',  # '25 Oct 2006', 
    '%d %B %Y',  # '25 October 2006', 
)
```

in settings.py solves the problem.